# Valid replacement for PowerPivot on using a MySql database for DataStore

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

**Scenario**

I would definitely have to say that I am in no means an Excel Wizard. I do manage to run the application and BI side of things for my company. We have approximately 80 users utilizing PowerPivot through a MSSQL data warehouse. This data warehouse is a mess and being rebuilt currently, there is a likelihood that the rebuild will not be in MSSQL as most of our new development and ETL is in PostgreSQL and MySQL; there is a 90% chance this will be MySQL.

**Problem**

Given that scenario I am in a quandary on how I can handle the users currently utilizing PowerPivot. While I do not have a full understanding of the Microsoft Power* tools, I do know that the PowerPivot tool is semi-functional with MySQL. It does not have the ability to Select Tables due to the SQL query conventions, unfortunately this is a heavily used feature of our end users but I know that "Excel for MySQL" handles that part, but does it match what PowerPivot can do?

**Questions**

1. What differences are there between PowerPivot and MySQL for Excel in
   functionality and usage?
2. Are there other Excel tools that provide
   the same sort of functionality as PowerPivot?
3. Does PowerQuery provide any functionality benefit when using MySQL vs. MSSQL

Comment: Why MySQL over Postgres?

Comment: Acceptance, skillset, and usability. I use Postgres for our web applications (.NET) but the question details usage at the client side. Postgres suffers the same issue as MySQL in the PowerPivot category (no table view), is a bit more obtuse in configuring for PowerQuery (client side GAC), and doesn't have a specific Pivot plugin like MySQL (MySQL for Excel) does. If the question can be answered in regards to Postgres then I am definitely willing to read.

Comment: That helps clarify things. I've found that generally speaking PostgreSQL is far more SQL compliant and has almost none of the quirky limitations MySQL has, but if you've got a specific use case, MySQL could be the way to go. I'd be sure to evaluate Percona vs. MariaDB vs. Oracle MySQL before you deploy.